# how to insert this background image url in printf php?

Tags: php, url, hyperlink, printf, echo

i want to add this background image :

`style="background-image: url( '<?php echo $this->video->category->image; ?>' );"`

inside /a href=""/ under this printf :

`printf( ' <a href="%s">%s</a>', YendifVideoShareRoute::getCategoryRoute( $this->video->category, $this->params->get( 'itemid_category' ) ), $this->escape( $this->video->category->title ) );`

to be like this :

`<a style="background-image: url( '<?php echo $this->video->category->image; ?>' );" href="%s">%s</a>`

but echo not works in printf .

Answer (score 0):

```php
printf(
  ' <a style="background-image: url( \'%s\' );" href="%s">%s</a>',
  $this->video->category->image,
  YendifVideoShareRoute::getCategoryRoute( $this->video->category, this->params->get( 'itemid_category' ) ),
  $this->escape( $this->video->category->title )
);
```

All `printf()` does is replace placeholders, eg: `%s`, with the subsequent arguments to the function, optionally applying some formatting accoring to how the placeholder is written.

Ref: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf

Also worth mentioning is `sprintf()` which works exactly the same, but returns the result as a string instead of dumping it to output.

Comment: not works ... not show the image and dreamwaver display errors .